# How to save excel file using phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel

I am writing some code to open an excel file then creating a new column and appending the data from column 2 to column 1. However the file is not saving.

I am loading this data in my local Wamp. The project is in Laravel

// create new file with results
        $date = new \DateTime();

```
    // create new file with results
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $directory = base_path() . '/storage/tmp/';


    /** Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object **/
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
    {
        $worksheet->insertNewColumnBefore('A', 1); //To insert a single new column before column A:

        foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
        {
            $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'AFS-' . $worksheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue());
        }
    }

    $convertedFileName = "converted-file". $date->getTimestamp().".xlsx";
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save($directory . $convertedFileName);
```

Comment: `$convertedFileName` !== `$convertedFile`

Comment: I made that change as seen above. Still the same issue.

Comment: Then check directory permissions, logs for any errors, etc