# How can I rewrite this code for maatwebsite/excel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using laravel. I want to read an excel file and add a new column to the left of the first column on each sheet using PHP. (The excel file can have as many as 10 sheets)

concatenate "AFS-" to the data in each row of the first column and store the new string in the new column to the left.

Eg.
[image]

**Code Below.**

```
        $finalFile = "";
        /** Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object **/
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
        {
            $worksheet->insertNewColumnBefore('A', 1); //To insert a single new column before column A:

            foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
            {
                $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'AFS-' . $worksheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue());
            }
        }

        $convertedFileName = "converted-file". $date->getTimestamp().".xlsx";
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save($directory . $convertedFileName);
```

Comment: so what's so much more different than your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020292/how-to-save-excel-file-using-phpexcel

Comment: The other question is asking for the code to be fixed. This question is asking for a solution to writing the same code using another class

Comment: So did you bother checking directory permissions, looking in the logs for any errors, etc as suggested in that previous question?

Comment: There are no errors in the logs. everything seems to be configured properly.

Comment: Based on what I see, maatexcel is designed to work with laravel. Thats why I am checking how to rewrite it. Not seeing enough documentations on it online.